# Is it necessary to use the bash code appended to ~/.bash_profile by anaconda?

Tags: python, bash, anaconda, conda

After I install anaconda on Mac OS X, I got the following append to ~/.bash_profile. I am wondering what is the purpose of `conda shell.bash hook` (output shown below). Is it sufficient to just add `/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin/` to $PATH. Instead of using the bash code appended to `~/.bash_profile`?

```
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```

```
$ conda shell.bash hook
export CONDA_EXE='/Users/pengy/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda'
export _CE_M=''
export _CE_CONDA=''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='/Users/pengy/opt/anaconda3/bin/python'

# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

__add_sys_prefix_to_path() {
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
    else
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${SYSP}")
    fi

    if [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Scripts:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/usr/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/mingw-w64/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}:${PATH}"
    else
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
    fi
    \export PATH
}

__conda_hashr() {
    if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        \rehash
    elif [ -n "${POSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        :  # pass
    else
        \hash -r
    fi
}

__conda_activate() {
    if [ -n "${CONDA_PS1_BACKUP:+x}" ]; then
        # Handle transition from shell activated with conda <= 4.3 to a subsequent activation
        # after conda updated to >= 4.4. See issue #6173.
        PS1="$CONDA_PS1_BACKUP"
        \unset CONDA_PS1_BACKUP
    fi

    \local cmd="$1"
    shift
    \local ask_conda
    OLDPATH="${PATH}"
    __add_sys_prefix_to_path
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA shell.posix "$cmd" "$@")" || \return $?
    PATH="${OLDPATH}"
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}

__conda_reactivate() {
    \local ask_conda
    OLDPATH="${PATH}"
    __add_sys_prefix_to_path
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA shell.posix reactivate)" || \return $?
    PATH="${OLDPATH}"
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}

conda() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            activate|deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
                ;;
            install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
                OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${OLDPATH}"
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate
                else
                    return $t1
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${OLDPATH}"
                return $t1
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}

if [ -z "${CONDA_SHLVL+x}" ]; then
    \export CONDA_SHLVL=0
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA+x}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    else
        PATH="$(\dirname "$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    fi
    \export PATH

    # We're not allowing PS1 to be unbound. It must at least be set.
    # However, we're not exporting it, which can cause problems when starting a second shell
    # via a first shell (i.e. starting zsh from bash).
    if [ -z "${PS1+x}" ]; then
        PS1=
    fi
fi


conda activate base
```